# Why do we need pointer to a structure pointer to change members value?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

While for simple types `(simple types: int, char..)` we directly use pointers `(their address)` as an argument to a function to permanently change their value in the main program, can someone explain to me why for structures we need a pointer to a `Structure pointer`, and not just a pointer?

```
struct someStruct
{
  int field1;
  int field2;
}

void initializeFields(struct someStruct** foo)
{
  //changing fields
}

//while 
void initializeFields(struct someStruct* foo) //does not work ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only change the members of the structure you don't need that. But to change the actual pointer *to* the structure you need to emulate *pass by reference* by using pointer to a pointer to the structure.

For example, to only change a member this is enough

```
void initializeFields(struct someStruct* foo)
{
    foo->field1 = 1;
    foo->field2 = 2;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct someStruct bar;
    initializeFields(&bar);
    printf("field1 = %d\n", bar.field1);
    printf("field2 = %d\n", bar.field2);

    return 0;
}
```

But if you for example want to dynamically allocate the structure in the function you need to emulate pass by reference:

```
void initializeFields(struct someStruct** foo)
{
    // The difference is this assignment
    *foo = malloc(sizeof(struct someStruct));

    (*foo)->field1 = 1;
    (*foo)->field2 = 2;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct someStruct* bar;
    initializeFields(&bar);
    printf("field1 = %d\n", bar->field1);
    printf("field2 = %d\n", bar->field2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Two more examples to show the difference between pass by value and emulating pass by reference.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int y)
{
    y = 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    printf("1: x = %d\n", x);
    foo(x);
    printf("2: x = %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

The above program will print

```
1: x = 1
2: x = 1
```

That is because a *copy* of the value in `x` is passed to the function `foo`. Modifying the local copy inside `foo` will not modify the original variable `x` inside `main`.

Now to emulate pass by reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *y)
{
    *y = 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    printf("1: x = %d\n", x);
    foo(&x);
    printf("2: x = %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

This program will print

```
1: x = 1
2: x = 5
```

This is because we don't change the pointer variable `y` inside the function `foo`, but we change the value of where it points, which happens to be the variable `x` in the `main` function.

Comment: I see, but why in the second case we need pointer to a pointer to return the malloc'd memory? why can't we pass only a pointer to foo ?

Comment: Is it really a good practice ? I mean, returning a struct pointer allocated inside initializeFields sounds way better than allocating in a pointer of a pointer and return nothing, not even an error code in case of malloc failure.

Comment: @Bionix1441 Because C only have what is called *pass by value*, which means a copy is created for the passed argument. Modifying a copy will of course not modify the original. If you have a function that takes an `int` argument, and in the function you modify the argument, would you expect the value you pass to the function in the call to be modified?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So if I understood you correctly : to modify `int` we need a pointer, to modify the actual pointer we need pointer to this pointer

Comment: @Bionix1441 Correct. Added a couple of example to show that with integers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you

Comment: @Bionix1441 When you want to modify something passed as a parameter, you need a pointer to that thing.

Answer (score 3):

`struct someStruct* foo` is fine, you don't need `struct someStruct** foo`. Not sure where you got that idea from, but it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are very specific cases where you need pointer to a struct pointer (array of struct pointers, mostly).

Otherwise, a pointer to a struct is enough.

```
struct someStruct
{
    int field1;
    int field2;
}

void initializeFields(struct someStruct* foo)
{
    foo->field1 = 42;
    foo->field2 = -1;
}
```